# Neviim and Ketuvim in 1-2 volumes

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, translation, navi-prophets, ketuvim

It’s possible to buy a Chumash containing Rashi comments in one volume (e.g. Artscroll Schottenstein Interlinear ed.).

Having a Chumash, I’d like to buy Hebrew/English Nevi’im and Ketuvim with comments (Rashi or multiple authors) in one volume each or together.

Would you please say what options are there? What publisher?

P.S. I know that there is an option to buy a one volume Tanakh, but as I understand a font is too small there or there are no comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very nice option from Koren Publishers with the commentary of R Steinsaltz, which is a digest of all standard commentators (e.g., Rashi, Radak, Metsudat David). The commentaries are interpolated in the text to make it highly readable, and specific comments are brought down on the sides of the text. You can see it for yourself in the extracts below.

There are two volumes, one each for [Neviim](https://korenpub.com/products/steinsaltz-tanakh-neviimhardcover) (detailed extract [here](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0229/0080/1614/files/neviim_extract.pdf?v=9376981558244668598)) and [Ketuvim](https://korenpub.com/products/the-steinsaltz-ketuvim) (detailed extract [here](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0229/0080/1614/files/look_inside_Steinsaltz_Ketuvim.pdf?13478&16195)).

Beyond this, [artscroll](https://www.artscroll.com/Categories/30N.html) has both Neviim and Ketuvim editions, but they take many volumes (13 in total) and might be too detailed for what you have in mind.